# How to know the OpenVPN version in the Synology VPN Server package?

Tags: openvpn, synology-diskstation

How can I know which version of OpenVPN is contained inside the package "VPN Server" 1.4.7-2901 on my Synology NAS? Package description is a one-liner only...

Answer (score 1):

You must connect to DSM on ssh and use command:

```
 openvpn --version
```

Answer (score -2):

openvpn --version

OpenVPN **2.5.4** [git:DSM7-1/b702bec612113074+] x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Dec  1 2021

library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023, LZO 2.10

BUT soon this is getting released:
DSM Version: 7.2-64551 Release Candidate (2023-04-29)
[...] Updated OpenVPN to version **2.5.8** to fix a security vulnerability (CVE-2022-0547).

Comment: You don't need the output to show the answer, but you do need a little more explanation. Please edit your answer to make it more complete. Also, note that the other answer posted here already says exactly the same thing, but is better because of just a little explanation. Avoid adding answers to already answered questions that do not actually add any new information.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1185710)

Comment: music2myear: are you serious? the answer is in the first line and it was NOT answered before: OpenVPN 2.5.4. the rest is vital info for anyone wanting to know more about what is under the hood of Synology NAS OpeNPVN Package. It can help one to set up his config properly regarding the undocumented (by Synology) features.

Comment: First, the question was answered with more information and a grammatically correct ANSWER 20 days before you posted your comment. Second, your comment only says a cmd, and does not list any further explanation. All your comment needs is a sentence or two, but, even given that, your comment does not add anything more helpful than the better answer posted by antopoz.